# How to run a python program using Singularity from a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, singularity-container

I have created a docker container for my pure python program and have set `python main.py` to be executed when the container is run. Running the container works as expected on my local machine. However, I want to run the container on my institution's high-performance cluster. The cluster machines use [Singularity](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.3/user-guide/), which I am using to pull my docker image hosted on Dockerhub (the repo is darshank11/ga_paci_final). However, when I try to run the Singularity container, I get the following error: `python3: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

I've tried to change the base image in the Dockerfile, for example from `FROM python:latest` to `FROM ubuntu:latest.` I've made sure the docker container worked on my local machine, and then got one of my co-workers to pull the container from Dockerhub and run it too. Everything works fine until I get to Singularity.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev

RUN mkdir src
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "-u", "main.py"]
```

Comment: where have you stored the main.py file? if under /src, can you try `CMD ["python3", "-u", "/src/main.py"]` ?

Comment: The main.py file is stored in the working directory in local, and then copied over to the src directory. Also, since I set `WORKDIR /src`, I should be able to run `python3 main.py`. Everything works in a normal docker container, only the conversion using singularity causes problems.

Comment: The singularity image is built using the Dockerfile / Docker image, but some things don't carry over. Working directory context is one of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because the execution context is not what you're expecting. The run path in singularity is the current directory on the host OS (e.g., `~/ga_paci_final`), which has been mounted into the singularity image.

As mentioned in the comments, one solution is to give the full path to the python file in the docker `CMD` statement. Another option is to modify the `%runscript` block of singularity definition file to something like:

```
%runscript
    cd /src
    python3 -u main.py
```

That way you ensure the run environment is identical between Docker and Singularity.

Comment: Do I have to include both a Dockerfile and Singularity recipe in my project directory?

Comment: It depends! If you don't want to juggle multiple container definition files and still have it work on both Docker and Singularity, you can build directly from the docker image: `sudo singularity build ga_paci.simg docker://darshank11/ga_paci_final:first_try`. In that case, rather than specifying the full path as mentioned above, instead call a bash script that ensures the environment is set up correctly. Simplistic example here: https://gist.github.com/tsnowlan/bd31dd497b24d1a48ce64d6befdfc215